# HttpListener doesn't get parameters with # symbol

Tags: c#, .net

I start server this way:

```
HttpListener httpListener = new HttpListener();
httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:11000/");
httpListener.Start();
while (true)
{
     HttpListenerContext context = httpListener.GetContext();
     HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
}
```

Then send two request:

1. http://localhost:11000/?abc=123
2. http://localhost:11000/?#abc=123

HttpListener catches first request with parameters, but second without any parameters. I need it because I'm trying implement Facebook Outh and move Facebook answer to my WPF App that listen special port, but Facebook response contains this symbol "#".
How I can recieve all parameters, if get request contains # symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser never sends the part of uri after #.
It is by design, since # url fragments are used for client side navigation.

see RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-4

If the code running on client can be altered by you, you can store the part of URI in an http header, or some other body part of the request.